# Openstack node software update

Tags: ubuntu, updates, openstack, auto-update, juju

The setup was originally done with juju bundle deployment using the bundle for focal and wallaby.

Can I set up the unattended update for the nodes (and lxd containers) to use "${distro_id}:${distro_codename}-updates" as an allowed update or will it break anything?

On the same lines - can I execute the "apt update && apt -y dist-upgrade" on the nodes and containers without breaking anything? If not - how can I do the OS updates without breaking anything.

Answer (score 0):

You can update your packages on the cloud nodes but don't introduce any new package archives.